# Default value for new lookup fields

Tags: soql, lookup, sobject

I have created a lookup between two custom objects.
Object A is an existing object that has a new lookup to object B, a new object.

For the next few months I need to have a scheduled batchjob to keep the new lookup field populated on new records of object A

In order to find all records that do not have a lookup to B I have tried the following SOQL:

```
SELECT Id, LookupB__c FROM A__c
WHERE LookupB__c= NULL
```

It returns zero records. I get the same result if I try with an empty string ('')

If I run the query without the WHERE clause and then print the content of lookupB__c, it tells me it is *null*

So what should I use to find the records where the lookup is not set?

Comment: Are you sure it does not work? I did the same on my org.
`SELECT Id, LookupField__c FROM ObjectWithLookup__c WHERE LookupField__c = null`. 
Do you have View All Data on Profile?

Comment: I am Admin so I don't think that is the problem.
I was running the queries from my IDE, I just tried from the developer console. That works. And it also works from my IDE now. 
I have not changed the query at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran the query I the developer Console instead of in my IDE.
It works now, the query have not been changed.

I have no explanation.